# Finding children where attributes are not the same

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Here is my issue. 

I have 100,000+ `Products` that each have 5-6 `Variants`. 

They were all uploaded via a CSV file with their information(pricing, sizes, descriptions, image urls, etc.)

The problem is, there were many errors in the CSV file with pricing. All SM-XL sizes should be the same, but they are not.

I would like to go through and change all the variants where the SM-XL prices are not the same, to the highest priced variant.

For example, if I have a "SM" sized product @ $13.34 and I have a "MD" sized product @ $14.44 and I have a "LG" sized product @ $12.29... I want them all changed to $14.44

Could I get some advice on the best way to do this without killing my app's memory? I could loop through each `Product's` `variants` but that would take up way too much resources, I would think. I can't imagine how long it would take to go through close to 1,000,000 objects and make updates when necessary.

Comment: What database are these values saved in?

Comment: It is a PostgreSQL database

Comment: You should first dump all the records from CSV file to temporary table in db regardless of errors. Then update that temporary table according to your needs and copy the required content into your actual table. Also while reading large CSV files you should read it in chunks to reduce the resource usage. You can use `roo` gem for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the update in one SQL query like this:

```
UPDATE variants
SET price=subquery.max_price 
FROM (
  SELECT product_id AS pid, max(price) AS max_price FROM variants GROUP BY pid
) AS subquery 
WHERE product_id=subquery.pid;
```

Either run it directly from console or create a rake task which will run it for you.

Comment: I have other variants that are not the same price, also. For instance, the "XXL" size would be different, and I would not want those to be changed. Just the SM-XL sizes.

Comment: You can add WHERE condition to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll inevitably have to do iterations, and even if you don't, it's going to use a lot of memory regardless. Could you run the process as a background job using Sidekiq or something similar?

Either way, you would definitely want to keep your queries compact as possible. The first thing that comes to mind is something like:

```
products = { 1 => { "price" => 14.44 }, 2 => { "price" => 14.44 } }
Product.update(products.keys, products.values)
```

That said, I think you'll squeeze out a lot more efficiency by doing a raw SQL query, so you may want to pose this question as an SQL question rather than Ruby on Rails. To do an SQL query in Rails:

```
query = <<-SQL 
  SELECT * 
  FROM products
  WHERE price != 14.44
SQL
```

That's a terrible query, but you get the idea.